# session value getting changed CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

session getting overwritten when passing from one controller to another CodeIgniter

i have set the session value as

```
$dbname = $this->session->set_userdata(array('newdb'=>'some_value'));
```

And when i display from there its showing the correct value

But its automatically getting changed to different value , that's "assets" when passing that from one controller to another
so when i print the value its coming as

```
   [userdata]=> newdb => 'assets'
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Even I have bumped into this issue suddenly and have no clue...

Comment: not really but found from where that assets is coming, its a file path being getting saved , assets/images/login.png  . i am doing other features so left it at that., please do let me know if u found a way out

Comment: Thanks for your response. First, I think you're correct about the word 'asset' being a path. On the other hand, I think the reason for this is some data stored in the session variable. This only happens when a specific value is stored in a session variable. Anyway, even I decided to use an alternative solution - passing data in the uri segment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need assigning to variable `$dbname` when setting the session. I believe it is just returned as `TRUE`. Just set session as `$this->session->set_userdata( [ 'newdb' => 'some_value' ] );` and call that value in some next request as `$newdb = $this->session->userdata( 'newdb' );`

```
$this->session->set_userdata( [ 'newdb' => 'some_value' ] );
$newdb = $this->session->userdata( 'newdb' );
//var_dump( $newdb ); 
$this->session->unset_userdata( 'newdb' ); 
//var_dump( $newdb );
```

Comment: i am able to get the value in the same controller view ... but when its transfered only somehow the value is changed to "assets" .... i tried changing the index of array ,,then also its coming "assets" dont know from where this "assets" is coming

Comment: You have some pre_controller injection. Maybe `MY_Controller`, hook or loaded library with constructor return?

Comment: i have created a MY_Controller_db which extends MY_controller , i am getting which db to select through url and trying to pass the same through session